# Where does an email go after removing a label in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I will try to walk through the scenario which leads up to my questions.

Steps:

1. I get an email in my inbox
2. I drag it over to a label.  So the email is removed from the inbox and shows up when I click on the label.
3. Now, when I am looking at the detailed message and I see the labels listed at the top of the mail.  If I click the X on the right of the label in the email to remove it, that works but my question is :

Where does this email go now?  I don't see it in the inbox, it is no longer in the view of that label.

Where does an email go in this situation?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

All mail in Gmail is in the **All Mail** label, unless the message is deleted. Even **Inbox** is just a label. When you add or remove a label, the email is still in **All Mail**, it just also shows up in the other label if it's labeled.

Note: even **All Mail** is a label, it just is the only one that can't be removed (except by deleting the message).

Answer (score 1):

> Where does this email go now? I don't see it in the inbox, it is no longer in the view of that label.
>
> Where does an email go in this situation?

The emails remains in *All mails* because it is label too.. now if you are asking how to get these mails in the Inbox follow this..

Go to Manage labels at the bottom of Inbox... then go to filters and remove the filter settings in order to see those mails back in your inbox

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar question to this so I ran a test. I put both incoming and outgoing emails into a label called test and then deleted the label. The sent email was still in the sent label and the other that should have reverted to the inbox was not there. I was able to search it and find it but could not find the label. I noticed it had an arrow symbol pointing to the right so I looked down in the list of labels and notice one called "important" with a similar arrow. I believe the arrow I saw meant the message was forwarded but it still led me to the important label because the symbol is similar. I went into this label and there was the email I was looking for.

Now trying to find a way to make these revert back to the inbox.